# Types and classes in Python

Tags: python, class, types

I'm a bit confused about types and classes in Python. For e.g. the following REPL conversation confuses me:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<type 'instance'>
>>> a.__class__
<class __main__.A at 0xb770756c>
>>> type([])
<type 'list'>
>>> [].__class__
<type 'list'>
>>> type(list)
<type 'type'>
>>> list.__class__
<type 'type'>
>>> type(A)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> A.__class__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__class__'
```

1. Why is the type and class for inbuilt things (e.g. list here) the same but different for user classes/types?
2. Isn't every class an instance of some other class (like Class in Java)? Why no `__class__` for user defined classes?

Any explanation/further reading which can clarify this behaviour would be much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: You should define your classes with `class A(object)`. Then you will get `<class '__main__.A'>` for `type(a)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're encountering the different behavior for new style classes versus classic classes.  For further reading read this: [Python Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).  Specifically read the section on classes and the difference between new style and classic classes.

Try typing the following into your REPL:

```
class A: pass
class B(object): pass
```

and you'll see that you get different results.  Here you're dealing with the difference between new style and old style classes.  Using Python 2.6.1 here's what I get:

```
> type(A)
<type "classobj">
> type(B)
<type "type">
```

which tells you that lists are new style classes and not old style classes.  We can further play around with things using `list` as well:

```
> type(list)
<type "type">
```

same as our `class B(object): pass` result.  And also

```
> c = []
> type(c)
<type "list">
```

which is telling you about the instance of the object and not it's definition.

Comment: It seems that my wrong was with not using new typeclasses which ended up giving me weird results (surely for backward compatibility). The link looks interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's "Hystorical reasons". Or possible "Histerical". It's all fixed in Python 3:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
>>> [].__class__
<class 'list'>
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
>>> list.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> type(A)
<class 'type'>
>>> A.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> class B(object): pass
... 
>>> type(B)
<class 'type'>
>>> b = B()
>>> type(b)
<class '__main__.B'>
```

Comment: That's nice to know.  Didn't realize Python 3 had fixed the issue all together.  I assume then, that all classes regardless of explicitly deriving from `object` derive from `object` then?

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.0, user-defined class objects are instances of the object named type,
which is itself a class.
• In Python 2.6, new-style classes inherit from object, which is a subclass of type;
• classic classes are instances of type and are not created from a class.