# Perl's Inline::Python fails on pyephem

Tags: python, perl, pyephem

```
#!/bin/perl 

use Inline Python; 

$s = new Sun(); 
print "SUN: $s\n"; 
$m = new Moon(); 

__END__ 
__Python__ 
from ephem import Sun as Sun; 
from ephem import Moon as Moon;
```

The code above yields:

```
SUN: <Sun "Sun" at 0x9ef6f14>
Can't bless non-reference value at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/i386-linux-thread-multi/Inline/Python.pm line 317.
```

What's wrong? I've tried this with many other objects (eg:

```
from ephem import Observer as Observer;
```

and then

```
$o= new Observer();
```

in the body of my code) and it works fine for everything I've tried *EXCEPT* Moon.

EDIT (probably useless information):

In https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/tree/master/libastro-3.7.5 :

- The routines for calculating Sun, Mercury, Venus, Mars (the ones 
  that work fine) are done in vsop87.c, function vsop87()
- The routines for calculating Jupiter, Saturn, etc (the ones that 
  don't work) are done in chap95.c, function chap95()
- vsop87() "returns" an array of 6 doubles, which appear to be some 
  sort of spherical coordinates.
- chap95() "returns" an array of 6 doubles, which appear to be 
  Cartesian coordinates, ie, rectangular and NOT spherical.
- planpos() in plans.c calls one of the two functions above, 
  depending on which planet you choose. What's odd is that planpos() 
  treats the function results the same (sort of), even though they 
  return very different things.
- After planpos(), all planets are treated the same. planpos() is 
  called by plans() (also in plans.c), which is in turn called by 
  obj_planet() in circum.c which is then called by obj_cir() also in 
  circum.c
- obj_planet() and obj_cir() define the planet. Since planets are 
  treated the same after planpos(), there should be no difference 
  between them.

Comment: Jupiter and Saturn also do not work, but Mercury and Venus work. The three non-working are somehow special-cased in the python code.

Comment: I also tried Mars earlier, and it works. I don't know if there IS any Python code... I think the Python stuff is just bindings to a C library, libastro.

Comment: There's some glue python code, on my system in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ephem/__init__.py`. I see special handling for Moon, Jupiter, and Saturn there. The comment says "We now replace two of the classes we have just created, because _libastro actually provides separate types for two of the bodies."

Comment: @SlavenRezic You are correct. Sadly, "from ephem import _libastro.Moon as Moon;" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed the different handling for the Moon, Jupiter and Saturn bodies, as pointed out by Slaven in the comments. 
In fact, you're running into the Python 2 issue that there is a difference between `types` and `classes`. I can't give you the details, but there is [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479819/types-and-classes-in-python) [a bit of](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) [material](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/) on the subject.

Suffice to say, that the Python wrapper provided by PyEphem turns the bodies into a proper class, which `Python::Inline` can handle. The Python-C wrapper, `_libastro`, provides types instead, and thus setting `Moon` to `_libastro.Moon` makes `Moon` a type instead of a class. Why `Python::Inline` can deal with classes and not types, I don't know.

This, however, provides enough information for a work-around: turn `ephem.Moon` into a class.
Thus, the following may work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Inline Python; 

$s = new Sun(); 
print "SUN: $s\n"; 
$m = new Moon(); 
print "Moon: $m\n";

__END__ 
__Python__ 
from ephem import Sun
from ephem import Moon
class Moon(Moon):
    pass
```

which for me results in:

```
SUN: <Sun "Sun" at 0x1f450b0>
Moon: <Moon "Moon" at 0x20eec50>
```

You can apply the same trick to Saturn and Jupiter of course.

(I've "Pythonized" the import statements a bit: no need for `as` or semi-colons.)

In case you'd like to verify that the Moon is still a special body even after turning it into a class, try to use on of its special attributes, for example `libration_lat`:

```
$m->compute()
$mllat = $m->{libration_lat};
print "Moon: ${mllat}\n";

Moon: 5:50:29.6
```

which will fail for any other type such as the Sun.

(I found these special attributes in `test_bodies.py` in the PyEphem package, though I presume these are documented as well. In case you'd like to test for Saturn and Jupiter, you can find them there.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In the interim, I discovered Skyfield... now, how to use that in Perl, hmmm.